# Analyze which level of a categorical variable has changed the most between two given distributions

Tags: r, statistical-significance, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I want to analyze whether the frequencies of a categorical variable X (e.g. icecream color) collected in a second survey are higher or lower than in a first survey.

I know that one can use Chi-square independence test to analyze if two categorical variables (here "survey time" and "icecream color") are independend from each other or not. Furthermore, Chi-square Goodness of Fit test can be used to check if the observed distribution of consumed icecream color differs significantly from a expected distribution.

For example, I have the following table containing frequencies for red, brown and yellow icecream and I want to find out if red icescream has higher frequencies in the second survey. I choose the Goodness of Fit Test:

```
second survey = c(20, 30, 90)
first survey  = c(12/140, 38/140, 90/140)

> X-squared = 7.0175, df = 2, p-value = 0.02993
```

As we can see, the distribution of icecream color has significantly changed between the two surveys.

Now my question is: How can one identify which level of icecream color has (significantly) changed the most towards a specific direction (in my case the second survey)? On my knowledge one can just look at a barplot and visually check this.

Comment: Other than a barplot, you can inspect the residuals of your $\chi$-squared analysis, except that it will highlight the direction in which the observed counts differ from the expected counts under the null (independence of the two variables). Mosaic plots with shaded regions (according to the values of the residuals) are frequently used to display such results.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for instance that anybody whants to know more details, I found this information also here: https://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_03.html

Comment: [A few other ideas](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/chi-square-test-of-independence-in-r).